# If $f$ is continuous and with a limit at infinity then $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let $f : [a, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, such that
>   $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = l \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that f is
>   uniformly continuous.

I want to split the domain - one in which we have continuity, and the other in which the values of f are approaching $l$. This means there are theree possibilities for our $x$ and $y$ using the uniformly continuous definition: x and y are in the first part, x and y are in the second, x is in the first and y in the second.

How would I do this proof?

Comment: To avoid splitting into three cases, you could allow the pieces to overlap and make sure to choose $\delta$ less than the width of the overlap. This avoids the case where $x$ is in one piece and $y$ is in the other.

Comment: @GregordeCillia A uniformly continuous function can have unbounded derivative

Comment: Yes. That's why I deleted my comment after a few mjnutes. I was thinking anout lipschitz continuouity and wanted to give an osciallator-like counterexample

Comment: Fix epsilon. Let delta(x) be the maximum delta used in the definition of continuity at x. Show delta(x) has a nonzero limit given the conditions of the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It suffices you do the following. Given $\epsilon>0$, take $N$ large so that, for $x>N$,

$$|f(x)- l|<\varepsilon/2$$

It follows that if $x,y>N$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Now consider the interval $[a,N+1]$, which is compact. Here $f$ is uniformly continuous, so there is some $\delta >0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. We can assume that $\delta<1$.

Consider now arbitrary $x,y\geqslant a$ that are at most $\delta$ units apart. If both $x,y\leqslant N+1$, then you're done. Our choice of $\delta$ is such that if $x> N+1$ then also $y>N$, and you're also done.

Comment: it is still true if limit at $\infty$ exist but not in R ?