# Show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is uniformly continuous in $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm concerned whether or not my choice of $\delta$ is appropriate here. Let $x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{R}$ and in this case $\vert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \vert$ equals $$\biggl\vert\frac{1}{1+x_1^2}-\frac{1}{1+x_2^2}\biggl\vert<\vert (x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2)\vert=\vert(x_1-x_2)\vert\cdot\vert(x_1+x_2)\vert$$

Notice that $\vert(x_1+x_2)\vert>0$. If we make sure that $\delta>\vert(x_1+x_2)\vert$, we can then claim that $$\vert(x_1-x_2)\vert\cdot\vert(x_1+x_2)\vert<\delta\cdot\vert(x_1-x_2)\vert<\delta^2$$

Now we can choose $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon }$, and the proof follows. I know $\delta$ can't depend on $x$, but other than that, can we restrict $\delta$ like this?

Comment: "If we make sure $\delta>|x_1+x_2|$"...... That's a problem, that's where you lose uniformity

Comment: But you've made $\delta$ depend on $x$.  $\delta>|x_1+x_2|$ There's no real number $\delta$ such that $\delta>|x_1+x_2|$ for all $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003989/if-f-is-continuous-and-with-a-limit-at-infinity-then-f-is-uniformly-continuo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

As people pointed your choice of $\delta$ does not work.

Instead try the following:

$$\biggl\vert\frac{1}{1+x_1^2}-\frac{1}{1+x_2^2}\biggl\vert=|x_1-x_2| \left| \frac{x_1+x_2}{(1+x_1^2)(1+x_2^2)}\right|$$

Now show that $2x_1 \leq 1+x_1^2$ and $2x_2 \leq 1+x_2^2$.

Comment: All too easy (+1)