# Uniformly continuous or not?

Tags: uniform-continuity

So I supposed to find out if $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\ln^2 x}$$ is uniformly continuous on $I=(0,\infty)$ So I have been thinking a lot. Could I say that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and therefore uniformly continuous here? Or is this not valid, because $\ln$ is not defined at $x=0$? And then say that the derivate is bounded at $[1,\infty]$?

Comment: The function $f$ is not defined at $x=0$...

Comment: Do you have some tips for how I can find out if it is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Presumable, you can define $f(0)=0$ to make it continuous on $[0,+\infty).$

Comment: @Mathomat55 have you checked that the function is differentiable and has bounded derivative?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. If I define $f(0)=0$ Can I after that use the same logic as above?

Comment: Yes, you can conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ after defining $f(0)$ to make $f$ continuous at $0.$ Not sure about the rest of your argument after that, though.

Comment: @Gibbs. It looks like the derivate is equal to $0$ when $x=1$. Then it has a minimumpoint between $x=1$ and $x=2$. As $x\rightarrow \infty f'(x)=0$ Won't the functions derivative be bounded then, since $0$ is the biggest value in that interval?

Comment: @Mathomat55 I think you have problems close to $x=0$. If you extend $f$ so that $f(0)=0$ then you can argue that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, thus uniformly continuous, whereas for $x>1$ the function is differentiable and the derivative is bounded, so it is uniformly continuous on $(1,\infty)$ as well.

Comment: @Gibbs Ok, so I'm thinking right then? I just have to define the function at $x=0$ first. Did you mean uniformly continuous at $[1,\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the function $f$ to a continuous function on $[0,+\infty)$.

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists and equal to zero. 
So we extend and define $f(0)=0$.

We use this theorem:-
**If $f:[0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.**

Then observe that,
 $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$$. 
This implies $f$ is uniformly continuous on
$[0,+\infty)$ and hence on $(0,+\infty)$

Comment: Ohh, I have never heard about that theorem before. Thank you!

Comment: You can find a more general version [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003989/779382) with proof.